# deploying Vue app with apache vhost shows white page

Tags: apache, vue.js, ubuntu

I'm trying to run a vue app with an apache vhost. But I just get to see a white page. Also my specified ServerAlias doesn't work and I have to use the IP. Using Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS

Apache vhost conf looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName testConnection.test
    ServerAlias www.testConnection.test
    ServerAdmin webmaster@test.de
    DocumentRoot /var/www/client/pvapp-client/public

    <Directory /var/www/client/pvapp-client/public>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        Allow from all
        AllowOverride All

        RewriteEngine on

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
        RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
        RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/test.com-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/test.com-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Vhost conf file is already enabled with the a2ensite command. And the standard conf file disabled.

Parts of the router.js look like:

```
const router = new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: Home
    },
    ....
```

And the vue.config.js regarding a tutorial:

```
module.exports = {
  baseUrl: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '/vue' : '/',
  outputDir: 'build',
};
```

As specified above the vue apps directory is:

```
/var/www/client/pvapp-client/[All Vue stuff]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved the problem for anyone who has the same issues in the future.

I needed to specify the root path as DIST not as PUBLIC:

```
...
DocumentRoot /var/www/client/pvapp-client/dist

<Directory /var/www/client/pvapp-client/dist>
...
```